# How to set select option from table cell value and display rest of database row value in another html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an quote that has tables for Item, description and price rate and want to select the item from an database select and display the description and price rate of the item in other table.

I'm new to PHP can someone please help.

```
                 <td>
                    <span contenteditable>
                       <div class="productSelect">
                          <select name="customer" id="customer">
                             <option value="" disabled selected>Click to See Products</option>
                             <?php
                                $records = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, name, sku, inventory_asset_acc, description, price_rate, cost, tax, quantity FROM addproducts");
                                    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
                                                    {
                                  
                                 echo '<option value="'.$data['id'].'" data-sku="' . $data['sku'].'" data-price_rate="' . $data['price_rate'].'" data-description="' . $data['description'] . '" data-quantity="' . $data['quantity'].'" >' . $data['name']. '</option>';
                                    
                                ?>
                              <?php } ?>
                          </select>
                           
                       </div>
                    </span>
                 </td>
                 <!------ Description -------->
                  
                 <td >
                     
                     <input style="width: 450px;" name="description" id="description" placeholder="&nbsp;"/>
                    <span contenteditable>
                    
                     
                     </span>
                 </td>
                  
                 <!------ Rate -------->
                 <td><span data-prefix id="price_rate" ></span><span  contenteditable></span></td>
```

Comment: Store the data in variables, use/output the variables where you want them?

Comment: Storing the data in variables only displays the last entry when output regardless of the item selected, how can i use the id to display the corresponding values of the item?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

PHP and HTML.

```
<!------ Item -------->
  <td>
   <span contenteditable>
    <div class="productSelect">
    <select name="table_info" id="table_info">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Click to See Products</option>
    <?php
    $records = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, name, sku, inventory_asset_acc, description, price_rate, cost, tax, quantity FROM addproducts");
   while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
   {
                                  
  echo '<option value="'.$data['name'].'" data-sku="' . $data['sku'].'" data-price_rate="' . $data['price_rate'].'" data-description="' . $data['description'] . '" data-quantity="' . $data['quantity'].'" >' . $data['name']. '</option>';
                                        
                                ?>
                              <?php } ?> 
                          </select>
                           
                       </div>
                    </span>
                 </td>
                 <!------ Description -------->
                  
                 <td>
                    <span contenteditable id="description">
                     </span>
                 </td>
                  
                 <!------ Rate -------->
                 <td> 
                     <span data-prefix >R</span><span contenteditable id="price_rate"></span>
                  </td>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
<script>
             
             var mySelectTwo = document.getElementById("table_info");
             
             mySelectTwo.addEventListener("change", function() {
                     
             var myNewOption = mySelectTwo.options[mySelectTwo.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price_rate");
             document.getElementById('price_rate').innerHTML = myNewOption;
                 
             var myNewOption = mySelectTwo.options[mySelectTwo.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-description");
             document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = myNewOption;
                     
                     
             });
```